# Unknown issue with Google Play Services after Updated app

Tags: android, google-play-services

Yesterday I updated my app and I am getting this error now on logCat

```
Authorization failed: server returned error: Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project..
```

Google API and Google SDK is ON for my app in console.developers.google.com

I only changed a text view's size on my app and I updated my beta test app. This is so wierd because app was running with no problems yesterday.

When I tried to sign-in with google play services a dialog appears and it says "Unknown issue with Google Play Services"